How to add play again feature into snake game
The majority of this code is from Bro Code's Python tutorial on how to make a snake game in Python. I decided to add a "Play again?" button on the game over screen, and when pressed would reset the game and allow the user to play again. The "new_game" function is the one I added.
from tkinter import *
import random

GAME_WIDTH = 600
GAME_HEIGHT = 600
SPEED = 75
SPACE_SIZE = 50
BODY_PARTS = 3
SNAKE_COLOR = "#0000FF"
FOOD_COLOR = "#FFFF00"
BACKGROUND_COLOR = "#000000"

class Snake:

    def __init__(self):
        self.body_size = BODY_PARTS
        self.coordinates = []
        self.squares = []

        for  i in range(0, BODY_PARTS):
            self.coordinates.append([0,0])

        for x, y in self.coordinates:
            square = canvas.create_rectangle(x, y, x + SPACE_SIZE, y + SPACE_SIZE, fill=SNAKE_COLOR, tag = "snake")
            self.squares.append(square)

class Food:

    def __init__(self):

        x = random.randint(0, int(GAME_WIDTH/SPACE_SIZE)-1) * SPACE_SIZE
        y = random.randint(0, int(GAME_HEIGHT/SPACE_SIZE)-1) * SPACE_SIZE

        self.coordinates = [x, y]

        canvas.create_oval(x, y, x + SPACE_SIZE, y + SPACE_SIZE, fill=FOOD_COLOR, tag="food")

def next_turn(snake, food):

    x, y = snake.coordinates[0]

    if direction == "up":
        y -= SPACE_SIZE

    elif direction == "down":
        y += SPACE_SIZE

    elif direction == "left":
        x -= SPACE_SIZE

    elif direction == "right":
        x += SPACE_SIZE

    snake.coordinates.insert(0, (x, y))

    square = canvas.create_rectangle(x, y, x + SPACE_SIZE, y + SPACE_SIZE, fill=SNAKE_COLOR,)

    snake.squares.insert(0, square)

    if x == food.coordinates[0] and y == food.coordinates[1]:

        global score

        score += 1

        label.config(text="Score: {}".format(score))

        canvas.delete("food")

        food = Food()

    else:
        del snake.coordinates[-1]

        canvas.delete(snake.squares[-1])

        del snake.squares[-1]

    if check_collisions(snake):
        game_over()

    else:
        window.after(SPEED, next_turn, snake, food)

def change_direction(new_direction):

    global direction

    if new_direction == 'left':
        if direction != 'right':
            direction = new_direction

    elif new_direction == 'right':
        if direction != 'left':
            direction = new_direction

    elif new_direction == 'up':
        if direction != 'down':
            direction = new_direction

    elif new_direction == 'down':
        if direction != 'up':
            direction = new_direction

def check_collisions(snake):

    x, y, = snake.coordinates[0]

    if x < 0  or x>= GAME_WIDTH:
        return True
    elif y < 0  or y >= GAME_HEIGHT:
        return True

    for body_part in snake.coordinates[1:]:
        if x == body_part[0] and y == body_part[1]:
            return True

    return False

def game_over():

    global canvas

    canvas.delete(ALL)
    canvas.create_text(canvas.winfo_width() / 2,
                       canvas.winfo_height() / 2,
                       font=('consolas', 70),
                       text="GAME OVER",
                       fill="red",
                       tag="gameover")

#**BUTTON I ADDED**

    again = Button(canvas,
                   width=12,
                   height=2,
                   text="Play again?",
                   font=('consolas', 15),
                   bg="black",
                   fg="red",
                   activebackground="black",
                   activeforeground="red",
                   command=new_game)
    again.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.65, anchor=CENTER)

# **FUCNTION SUPPOSED TO RESET GAME**

def new_game():

    global canvas

    score = 0

    canvas.destroy()
    label.config(text="Score:{}".format(score))

    canvas = Canvas(window,
                    bg=BACKGROUND_COLOR,
                    height=GAME_HEIGHT,
                    width=GAME_WIDTH)
    canvas.pack()


window = Tk()
window.title("Snake game")
window.resizable(False, False)

score = 0
direction = 'down'

label = Label(window,
              text="Score:{}".format(score),
              font=('consolas', 40))
label.pack()

canvas = Canvas(window,
                bg=BACKGROUND_COLOR,
                height=GAME_HEIGHT,
                width=GAME_WIDTH)
canvas.pack()

window.update()
window_width = window.winfo_width()
window_height = window.winfo_height()
screen_width = window.winfo_screenwidth()
screen_height = window.winfo_screenheight()

x = int((screen_width / 2) - (window_width / 2))
y = int((screen_height / 2) - (window_height / 2))

window.geometry(f"{window_width}x{window_height}+{x}+{y}")

window.bind('<Left>', lambda event: change_direction('left'))
window.bind('<Right>', lambda event: change_direction('right'))
window.bind('<Up>', lambda event: change_direction('up'))
window.bind('<Down>', lambda event: change_direction('down'))
window.bind('<a>', lambda event: change_direction('left'))
window.bind('<d>', lambda event: change_direction('right'))
window.bind('<w>', lambda event: change_direction('up'))
window.bind('<s>', lambda event: change_direction('down'))

snake = Snake()
food = Food()

next_turn(snake, food)

window.mainloop()

I successfully destroyed the "Game over" screen, added the original canvas back on the window, and reset the score, but I still don't know how to get the snake to appear again and start the game over again.
I've tried a while loop which would be True from the start and when the "Play again" was pressed would return False and the while loop would be broken. But that didn't change anything in the original window and just added an identical window when the original window was closed out of.

It doesn't look like you're touching the snake at all in the new_game() function. What are you doing to reset the snake to its initial conditions when the "Play Again" button is clicked?

That's kinda the thing... I don't know what to do to reset the snake back to its initial conditions when the "Play Again" button is clicked.

inside new_game you should use global score because you use score = 0. Without global it will not reset it.

in class Snake  you could add function reset() which removes from canvas all elements from list self.squares and later it runs the same code which you have in __init__ - and later you can run snake.reset() in new_game. Frankly, most code from initcould be inreset()and you could runreset()also ininit`

and in new_game you may have to create new food - to reset its position

it could be simpler to use canvas.clear() in new_game - to reset it (instead of destroy() and creating new canvas)

It can be something like this
def new_game():
    global score
    global direction
    global snake
    global food
    
    again.destroy()     # remove button
        
    score = 0           # reset score
    direction = 'down'  # reset direction

    canvas.delete('all')                 # reset canvas
    label.config(text=f"Score:{score}")  # reset label

    snake = Snake() # reset snake
    food = Food()   # reset food

    next_turn(snake, food)  # run again loop


With some changes you could even use it to run first game
new_game()
  
window.mainloop()

It would need to set again = None (because button doesn't exist yet but new_game() has to check variable again)
again = None

new_game()
  
window.mainloop()

def new_game():
    global score
    global direction
    global snake
    global food
    
    if again:
        again.destroy()

    # rest of code


Other idea is to move some part of code from __init__ to functions def reset(self)
class Snake:

    def __init__(self, canvas):
        self.canvas = canvas
        
        self.reset()    
    
    def reset(self):
        self.body_size = BODY_PARTS
        self.coordinates = []
        self.squares = []

        for _ in range(self.body_size):
            self.coordinates.append([0, 0])

        for x, y in self.coordinates:
            square = self.canvas.create_rectangle(x, y, x+SPACE_SIZE, y+SPACE_SIZE, fill=SNAKE_COLOR, tag="snake")
            self.squares.append(square)
    
class Food:

    def __init__(self, canvas):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.item_id = self.canvas.create_oval(0, 0, SPACE_SIZE, SPACE_SIZE, fill=FOOD_COLOR, tag="food")

        self.reset()
        
    def reset(self):
    
        x = random.randint(0, int(GAME_WIDTH/SPACE_SIZE)-1) * SPACE_SIZE
        y = random.randint(0, int(GAME_HEIGHT/SPACE_SIZE)-1) * SPACE_SIZE

        self.coordinates = [x, y]

        self.canvas.moveto(self.item_id, x, y)

and later use snake.reset() and food.reset() instead of creating objects again.

Full code:
import tkinter as tk  # PEP8: `import *` is not preferred
import random

GAME_WIDTH = 600
GAME_HEIGHT = 600
SPEED = 75
SPACE_SIZE = 50
BODY_PARTS = 3
SNAKE_COLOR = "#0000FF"
FOOD_COLOR = "#FFFF00"
BACKGROUND_COLOR = "#000000"

class Snake:

    def __init__(self, canvas):
        self.canvas = canvas
        
        self.reset()    
    
    def reset(self):
        self.body_size = BODY_PARTS
        self.coordinates = []
        self.squares = []

        for _ in range(self.body_size):
            self.coordinates.append([0, 0])

        for x, y in self.coordinates:
            square = self.canvas.create_rectangle(x, y, x+SPACE_SIZE, y+SPACE_SIZE, fill=SNAKE_COLOR, tag="snake")
            self.squares.append(square)
    
class Food:

    def __init__(self, canvas):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.item_id = self.canvas.create_oval(0, 0, SPACE_SIZE, SPACE_SIZE, fill=FOOD_COLOR, tag="food")

        self.reset()
        
    def reset(self):
    
        x = random.randint(0, int(GAME_WIDTH/SPACE_SIZE)-1) * SPACE_SIZE
        y = random.randint(0, int(GAME_HEIGHT/SPACE_SIZE)-1) * SPACE_SIZE

        self.coordinates = [x, y]

        self.canvas.moveto(self.item_id, x, y)
        

def next_turn(snake, food):
    global score  # PEP8: all `global` at the beginning of function

    x, y = snake.coordinates[0]

    if direction == "up":
        y -= SPACE_SIZE

    elif direction == "down":
        y += SPACE_SIZE

    elif direction == "left":
        x -= SPACE_SIZE

    elif direction == "right":
        x += SPACE_SIZE

    snake.coordinates.insert(0, (x, y))

    square = canvas.create_rectangle(x, y, x + SPACE_SIZE, y + SPACE_SIZE, fill=SNAKE_COLOR,)

    snake.squares.insert(0, square)

    if x == food.coordinates[0] and y == food.coordinates[1]:

        score += 1

        label.config(text="Score: {}".format(score))

        food.reset()

    else:
        del snake.coordinates[-1]

        canvas.delete(snake.squares[-1])

        del snake.squares[-1]

    if check_collisions(snake):
        game_over()

    else:
        window.after(SPEED, next_turn, snake, food)

def change_direction(new_direction):
    global direction

    if new_direction == 'left':
        if direction != 'right':
            direction = new_direction

    elif new_direction == 'right':
        if direction != 'left':
            direction = new_direction

    elif new_direction == 'up':
        if direction != 'down':
            direction = new_direction

    elif new_direction == 'down':
        if direction != 'up':
            direction = new_direction

def check_collisions(snake):

    x, y, = snake.coordinates[0]

    if x < 0  or x>= GAME_WIDTH:
        return True

    elif y < 0  or y >= GAME_HEIGHT:
        return True

    for body_part in snake.coordinates[1:]:
        if x == body_part[0] and y == body_part[1]:
            return True

    return False

def game_over():
    global again
    
    canvas.delete('all')
    canvas.create_text(canvas.winfo_width() / 2,
                       canvas.winfo_height() / 2,
                       font=('consolas', 70),
                       text="GAME OVER",
                       fill="red",
                       tag="gameover")

    again = tk.Button(canvas,
                   width=12,
                   height=2,
                   text="Play again?",
                   font=('consolas', 15),
                   bg="black",
                   fg="red",
                   activebackground="black",
                   activeforeground="red",
                   command=new_game)
    again.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.65, anchor='center')

def new_game():
    global score
    global direction
    global snake
    global food
    
    if again:
        again.destroy()
        
    score = 0           # reset score
    direction = 'down'  # reset direction

    canvas.delete('all')                 # reset calvas
    label.config(text=f"Score:{score}")  # reset label

    snake = Snake(canvas)  # reset snake
    food = Food(canvas)    # reset food

    #snake.reset()
    #food.reset()
    
    next_turn(snake, food)

# --- main ---

window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Snake game")
window.resizable(False, False)

label = tk.Label(window,
              text="Score:0",
              font=('consolas', 40))
label.pack()

canvas = tk.Canvas(window,
                bg=BACKGROUND_COLOR,
                height=GAME_HEIGHT,
                width=GAME_WIDTH)
canvas.pack()

window.update()
window_width = window.winfo_width()
window_height = window.winfo_height()
screen_width = window.winfo_screenwidth()
screen_height = window.winfo_screenheight()

x = int((screen_width / 2) - (window_width / 2))
y = int((screen_height / 2) - (window_height / 2))

window.geometry(f"{window_width}x{window_height}+{x}+{y}")

window.bind('<Left>', lambda event: change_direction('left'))
window.bind('<Right>', lambda event: change_direction('right'))
window.bind('<Up>', lambda event: change_direction('up'))
window.bind('<Down>', lambda event: change_direction('down'))
window.bind('<a>', lambda event: change_direction('left'))
window.bind('<d>', lambda event: change_direction('right'))
window.bind('<w>', lambda event: change_direction('up'))
window.bind('<s>', lambda event: change_direction('down'))

again = None # button to run again

new_game()

window.mainloop()

